# PHP how to add an Object from another file into a array in a different JSON

Tags: php, html, json

I want to move this object (in PHP)

(json1.json)

```
{
    "id": "TEST",
    "name": "TEST",
    "desc": "TEST",
    "image": "TEST",
    "package": "TEST",
    "version": "1.00",
    "picpath": "TEST",
    "desc_1": "ssss",
    "desc_2": "ssss",
    "ReviewStars": "5",
    "Size": "TEST",
    "Author": "TEST",
    "apptype": "222",
    "pv": "TEST",
    "main_icon_path": "TEST",
    "main_menu_pic": "TEST",
    "releaseddate": "2019-06-19",
}
```

into this array (json2.json)

```
{
  "packages": [
  {
      "id": "TEST",
      "name": "TEST",
      "desc": "TEST",
      "image": "TEST",
      "package": "TEST",
      "version": "1.00",
      "picpath": "TEST",
      "desc_1": "TEST",
      "desc_2": "TEST",
      "ReviewStars": "TEST",
      "Size": "",
      "Author": "TEST",
      "apptype": "TEST",
      "pv": "TEST",
      "main_icon_path": "TEST",
      "main_menu_pic": "TEST",
      "releaseddate": "5/03/2018"
    }
    ]
}
```

i want the final json to look like this

```
{
  "packages": [
  {
      "id": "TEST",
      "name": "TEST",
      "desc": "TEST",
      "image": "TEST",
      "package": "TEST",
      "version": "1.00",
      "picpath": "TEST",
      "desc_1": "TEST",
      "desc_2": "TEST",
      "ReviewStars": "TEST",
      "Size": "",
      "Author": "TEST",
      "apptype": "TEST",
      "pv": "TEST",
      "main_icon_path": "TEST",
      "main_menu_pic": "TEST",
      "releaseddate": "5/03/2018"
    },
{
    "id": "TEST",
    "name": "TEST",
    "desc": "TEST",
    "image": "TEST",
    "package": "TEST",
    "version": "1.00",
    "picpath": "TEST",
    "desc_1": "ssss",
    "desc_2": "ssss",
    "ReviewStars": "5",
    "Size": "TEST",
    "Author": "TEST",
    "apptype": "222",
    "pv": "TEST",
    "main_icon_path": "TEST",
    "main_menu_pic": "TEST",
    "releaseddate": "2019-06-19",
}

    ]
}
```

iv tried many solutions including this one

````
$datas[] = json_decode($json, true);

$datas[] = json_decode($json1, true);

$jsonData = json_encode($datas, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

file_put_contents($jpath, $jsonData);```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$json1_str = '{
    "id": "TEST",
    "name": "TEST",
    "desc": "TEST",
    "image": "TEST",
    "package": "TEST",
    "version": "1.00",
    "picpath": "TEST",
    "desc_1": "ssss",
    "desc_2": "ssss",
    "ReviewStars": "5",
    "Size": "TEST",
    "Author": "TEST",
    "apptype": "222",
    "pv": "TEST",
    "main_icon_path": "TEST",
    "main_menu_pic": "TEST",
    "releaseddate": "2019-06-19"
}';

$json2_str = '{
  "packages": [
  {
      "id": "TEST",
      "name": "TEST",
      "desc": "TEST",
      "image": "TEST",
      "package": "TEST",
      "version": "1.00",
      "picpath": "TEST",
      "desc_1": "TEST",
      "desc_2": "TEST",
      "ReviewStars": "TEST",
      "Size": "",
      "Author": "TEST",
      "apptype": "TEST",
      "pv": "TEST",
      "main_icon_path": "TEST",
      "main_menu_pic": "TEST",
      "releaseddate": "5/03/2018"
    }
    ]
}';

$json1 = json_decode($json1_str, true);
$json2 = json_decode($json2_str, true);

$json2['packages'][] = $json1;

$jsonData = json_encode($json2, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

echo $jsonData;
```

OUTPUT

```
{
    "packages": [
        {
            "id": "TEST",
            "name": "TEST",
            "desc": "TEST",
            "image": "TEST",
            "package": "TEST",
            "version": "1.00",
            "picpath": "TEST",
            "desc_1": "TEST",
            "desc_2": "TEST",
            "ReviewStars": "TEST",
            "Size": "",
            "Author": "TEST",
            "apptype": "TEST",
            "pv": "TEST",
            "main_icon_path": "TEST",
            "main_menu_pic": "TEST",
            "releaseddate": "5/03/2018"
        },
        {
            "id": "TEST",
            "name": "TEST",
            "desc": "TEST",
            "image": "TEST",
            "package": "TEST",
            "version": "1.00",
            "picpath": "TEST",
            "desc_1": "ssss",
            "desc_2": "ssss",
            "ReviewStars": "5",
            "Size": "TEST",
            "Author": "TEST",
            "apptype": "222",
            "pv": "TEST",
            "main_icon_path": "TEST",
            "main_menu_pic": "TEST",
            "releaseddate": "2019-06-19"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: No i want to add json1.json to json2.json not make it the same array